# Animation Rendering Error

Tags: rendering, animation, video

I’m new to animations and I just finished my second animation, but I have a problem when I press the ''Render Animation" Button, it only renders 1 picture/frame and when I open the file to where I saved it, it says “File isn’t supported or file is corrupt” that kind of stuff. Is anyone able to help me render my animation (video) please? Thank you!

Comment: To answer the question, we need to know how you render your animation (as *.png files? as *.mov file?). What are the output settings? What do you mean by "it only renders 1 picture/frame"? It should always be exactly 1 image per frame, right? What is the problem here?